# BadMethodCallException with Selenium and PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, methods, phpunit

I keep getting this error with alot of methods I am trying to use, here are a couple of code examlpes:

```
$this->verifyTextPresent('Hello world');
```

//BadMethodCallException: The command 'verifyTextPresent' is not existent or not s
upported yet.

```
$this->assertEquals("197", $this->getText("xpath=(//div[@id='none']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span)[29]"));
```

//BadMethodCallException: The command 'getText' is not existent or not supported y
et.

```
$this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

////BadMethodCallException: The command 'waitForPageToLoad' is not existent or not s
upported yet.

I am getting this error with alot of methods, and as far as i can see there is no problem with the code itself and my php version is up to date so it's nothing like that. anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

getting the same problem man ... 
I think there is a problem with selenium if you install it using pear. .

I tried re-installing the selenium and offered lord satan 5 pigs and 2 chicken..
still no good

now Im installing selium using composer... 
 I'll let you know what happen..

Edit***
Turns out using using phpunit.phar is the right answr. So I updated my phpunit . removed pear installed phpunit . then updated my composer.json to install phpunit and selenium .